# How to run large query without breakign execution time , or memory limit error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a code to copy post from a database where may have thousands of post, but now my query is breaking ,can any one let me know how can i run my code without breaking execution time , i have seen many wordpress plugin execute large query without any interruption.
Here is code

```
foreach($all_posts as $row ) {


        $post_exist = $tempdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$tempdb->prefix."posts WHERE ID=".$row->ID );

        if($post_exist) {
            $query = "UPDATE ".$tempdb->prefix."posts set post_date = '".$row->post_date."', post_date_gmt = '".$row->post_date_gmt."', post_modified='".$row->post_modified."', post_modified_gmt='".$row->post_modified_gmt."', post_author='".$row->post_author."', post_content='".$row->post_content."', post_title='".$row->post_title."',  post_status='".$row->post_status."', post_name='".$row->post_name."', post_type='".$row->post_type."', guid='".$row->guid."', ping_status='".$row->ping_status."', post_parent='".$row->post_parent."', post_mime_type='".$row->post_mime_type."' WHERE ID =".$row->ID; 

        }else {

            $query = "INSERT INTO ".$tempdb->prefix."posts set post_date = '".$row->post_date."', post_date_gmt = '".$row->post_date_gmt."', post_modified='".$row->post_modified."', post_modified_gmt='".$row->post_modified_gmt."', post_author='".$row->post_author."', post_content='".$row->post_content."', post_title='".$row->post_title."',  post_status='".$row->post_status."', post_name='".$row->post_name."', post_type='".$row->post_type."', guid='".$row->guid."', ping_status='".$row->ping_status."', post_parent='".$row->post_parent."', post_mime_type='".$row->post_mime_type."' "; 

        }
        $tempdb->query($query);

    }
```

Comment: maybe you should replace `COUNT(*)` by `COUNT(0)` for avoiding read the attributes, after all, you only want to know if a tuple exists. And make sure that an INDEX exists on the ID column.

Comment: `but now my query is breaking` Breaking how? Do you get errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: I said i want to copy post form other db where is thousands of posts.
@DarrenSweeney some time memory size exhausted, i fixed it by incrasing memory limit , and execution time exceeded error

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your script. 0 means the limit is not defined, which will make the script run forever.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

For the memory limit, it is related to the limits set by your own host. You said you increased that, which means there is no need to explain how. The point is, you even if you increase the limit it can't exceed the maximum set by your host and there isn't a specific way to solve the issue, and you'll need to find anoter host that provides enough resources if this persists.